# How do I align text inside a link to the left of the width of the link?

Tags: css

s you can see in the picture, the text inside the contact link is aligned to the right, I want it to align to the left so there is no redundant space inside it, I tried with text align: left inside the div but it didn't work, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: where is the picture & code ?

Comment: i cant see picture where it is??

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me upload a picture for some reason.

Comment: As a new user, you cannot post pictures until you gain some reputation. But you can use a free image-hosting service to upload your picture, and then post a link. If the picture is appropriate, a user with sufficient privileges will edit it inline for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align:left` or `float:left` style to that link style

Comment: I tried that. The "li" has an id of "item-111" so i tried #item-111 { text-align: left; } and #item-111 a { text-align: left; } but nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but i dont think this is gonna work without a picture, though I will try to explain better. The whole list is inside a div called #user11 and to make it horizontal I used #user11 { display: inline; float: left } to make it horizontal, but the problem is lets say for the "contact" link, the width is a 100 px and lets say the contact is 70px wide, then there is 30px of free space and THEN the contact appears and takes the rest of the width. there is no padding or margins.

Comment: did it! I set the #user li a to display inline and text-aligned to the left.